# Show Image Response Null If image Is Not Submitted In Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm Submitting data through postman in Laravel. I need to show the null value if data do not insert during submitting(In JSON response). But It did not show the image in response I need to show an image response also Null

My Store Code is

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $screenshots  = new Screenshots ;
    $screenshots->user_id = $request->user_id;
    $screenshots->name = $request->name;
    $screenshots->size = $request->size;

    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        $fileNameExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = pathinfo($fileNameExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $fileExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'.'.$fileExt;
        $pathToStore = $request->image->storeAs('public/uploads/screenshots', $request->image->getClientOriginalName());
        $screenshots->image = $fileNameToStore;
         $screenshots->save();
    };
    $screenshots->save();

    return $this->sendResponse($screenshots->toArray(), 'Command Send Successfully successfully.');

}
```

It is giving a null when any field is blank but if an image is blank I didn't any response.

For more clear please see attached screenshot 
[image]

Getting Response Be like

```
{"success":true,"data":{"user_id":"2","name":null,"size":"3.4kb","updated_at":"2020-02-12 07:26:49","created_at":"2020-02-12 07:26:49","id":32},"message":"Command Send Successfully successfully."}
```

The response I need if the image is also blank

```
{"success":true,"data":{"user_id":"2","name":null,"size":"3.4kb","image":"null","updated_at":"2020-02-12 07:26:49","created_at":"2020-02-12 07:26:49","id":32},"message":"Command Send Successfully successfully."}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use below method to add default set null

// set in your model Screenshots

```
 protected $attributes = array(
        'image' => '',
 );
```

OR

```
if($request->hasFile('image')){
        $fileNameExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = pathinfo($fileNameExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $fileExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'.'.$fileExt;
        $pathToStore = $request->image->storeAs('public/uploads/screenshots', $request->image->getClientOriginalName());
        $screenshots->image = $fileNameToStore;
         $screenshots->save();
    }else{
         $screenshots->image = '';   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Screenshots.php model define the default value of the attribute/property if it is not set as follows

```
class Screenshot extends Model {
    protected $attributes = ['image' => null];
}
```